# Using CTX in on_reaction_add event -- Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

```py
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    emoji = reaction.emoji
    if emoji == "":
    await user.channel.send("HI")
```

I got problem here with `user`.
I want to use here with ctx like `ctx.channel.send`.
but also it occured error how to use ctx in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `on_reaction_add` event, it's better in this case to use a `wait_for` command event. This would mean the event can only be triggered once and only when the command was invoked. However with your current event, this allows anyone to react to a message with that emoji and the bot would respond.

By using `client.wait_for("reaction_add")`, this would allow you to control when a user can react to the emoji. You can also add checks, this means only the user would be able to use the reactions on the message the bot sends. Other parameters can be passed, but it's up to you how you want to style it.

In the example below shows, the user can invoke the command, then is asked to react. The bot already adds these reactions, so the user would only need to react. The `wait_for` attribute would wait for the user to either react with the specified emojis and your command would send a message.

```py
@client.command()
async def react(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send('React to this message!')

    mail = ''
    post = ''

    await message.add_reaction(mail)
    await message.add_reaction(post)

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(
            reaction.emoji) in [mail, post]

    member = ctx.author

    while True:
        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=10.0, check=check)

            if str(reaction.emoji) == mail:
                await ctx.send('Hi you just received')


            if str(reaction.emoji) == post:
                await ctx.send('Hi you just posted...')
```

Comment: Hi i got ur problem and i will try it.
but if i do await client.wait_for("message", timeout=10.0, check=check) like this, how i have to do it?
i will make if someone say something, save it in database.
if i set something to specfic word, i can make code like if message == specfic msg,
but i dont know how to do at NOT Specfic msg.

like a = ctx.message.content
await client.wait_for("message", timeout=10.0, check=check)
if message == a:

this example will not worked but i want to work like this.

Comment: @HWS I'm not really sure what you mean. In your question, you just wanted to know to to use ctx in a reaction add, and the answer above allows that.  Are you wanting to know how to do an on_message?

Comment: Can you give me discord or telegram etc..? I can tell more there

Comment: Are you just wanting to do a wait_for message?

Comment: Yes. I want to make like this. If bot asks "what your name?" Then user say answer then the bot save answer in database. But i don't know how i catch answer with wait_for.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it needs an `except` at the end. What should be inside the `except`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `reaction.message.channel.send`

```py
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    emoji = reaction.emoji
    if str(emoji) == "": await reaction.message.channel.send("HI")
```

Comment: I tried it, there is not error but there is not worked

Comment: probably your if statement isnt triggering try the edited code